# android: file transfer through sockets

Tags: android

hi i am trying to send a file through sockets in an android messenger. for some reason its not working. at times it does output a file but transfers no bytes that is the output file is of 0 bytes and sometimes the output or the received file is of 57 bytes precisely. following the code where i actually send the file :

```
public boolean sendFile(String ip, int port) {      
     try {                      
         String[] str = ip.split("\\.");
         byte[] IP = new byte[str.length];
         for (int i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
             IP[i] = (byte) Integer.parseInt(str[i]);
         }
         Socket socket = getSocket(InetAddress.getByAddress(IP), port);
         if (socket == null) {
             return false;
         }
         Log.i("SocketOP", "sendFILE-1");
         File  f = new File("/sdcard/chats/gas.jpg/");
         filesize = (int) f.length();

         BufferedOutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream( socket.getOutputStream() );

         FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream(f);
         Log.i("SocketOP", "sendFILE-2");
         byte [] buffer  = new byte [filesize];
         int bytesRead =0;
         while ((bytesRead = fileIn.read(buffer)) > 0) {
             out.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
         }
         out.flush();
         out.close();
         fileIn.close();
         Log.i("SocketOP", "sendFILE-3");
     } catch (IOException e) {
         return false;          
         //e.printStackTrace();
     }
     return true;       
 }
```

this is where i send the inputstream to the receivefile method :

```
private class ReceiveConnection extends Thread {

    Socket clientSocket = null;
    public ReceiveConnection(Socket socket) {
        this.clientSocket = socket;
        SocketOperator.this.sockets.put(socket.getInetAddress(), socket);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            //PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                clientSocket.getInputStream()));
            String inputLine;

            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                InputStream is=clientSocket.getInputStream();
                if (inputLine.contains("Text") == true) {
                    appManager.messageReceived(inputLine);  
                    Log.i("SocketOP","text");

                } else if (inputLine.contains("Text") == false) {
                        Log.i("SocketOP","filee");
                        appManager.fileReceived(is);
                } else {
                    clientSocket.shutdownInput();
                    clientSocket.shutdownOutput();
                    clientSocket.close();
                    SocketOperator.this.sockets.remove(clientSocket.getInetAddress());
                    Log.i("SocketOP", "CLOSING CONNECTION");
                }                        
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and finally this is how i receive the file :

```
public void fileReceived(InputStream is)
    throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    Log.i("IMSERVICE", "FILERECCC-1");

    //int filesize=6022386; // filesize temporary hardcoded

    int bytesRead;

    final byte[] aByte = new byte[is.toString().length()];


    if (is!= null) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        BufferedOutputStream bos = null;
        try {
            fos = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/chats/gas1.jpg/");
            bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
            bytesRead = is.read(aByte, 0, aByte.length);

            do {
                baos.write(aByte);
                bytesRead = is.read(aByte);
            } while (bytesRead != -1);

            bos.write(baos.toByteArray());
            bos.flush();
            bos.close();
            Log.i("IMSERVICE", "FILERECCC-2");

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            // Do exception handling
        }
    }
}}
```

the following is the complete socketoperator file :

```
package hardy.scl.communication;

import hardy.scl.interfaces.IAppManager;
import hardy.scl.interfaces.ISocketOperator;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;

import android.util.Log;


public class SocketOperator implements ISocketOperator
{
private static final String AUTHENTICATION_SERVER_ADDRESS = "http://10.10.10.100/chippers/";

private int listeningPort = 0;

private static final String HTTP_REQUEST_FAILED = null;



private HashMap<InetAddress, Socket> sockets = new HashMap<InetAddress, Socket>();

private ServerSocket serverSocket = null;

private boolean listening;

private IAppManager appManager;

public int filesize ;



private class ReceiveConnection extends Thread {
Socket clientSocket = null;
Socket fileSocket=null;
public ReceiveConnection(Socket socket) 
{
    this.clientSocket = socket;
    this.fileSocket=socket;
    SocketOperator.this.sockets.put(socket.getInetAddress(), socket);
}

@Override
public void run() {
     try {
//          PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(),    true);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                   new InputStreamReader(
                            clientSocket.getInputStream()));



         InputStream is=fileSocket.getInputStream();

        String inputLine;
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)                  {



             if (inputLine.contains("Text") == true)
             {


                appManager.messageReceived(inputLine);  
        Log.i("SocketOP","text");}

             else  if 
            (inputLine.contains("Text") == false)
            {

                Log.i("SocketOP","filee");
                 appManager.fileReceived(is);

             }
            else{

                 clientSocket.shutdownInput();
                 clientSocket.shutdownOutput();
                 clientSocket.close();

                 fileSocket.shutdownInput();
                 fileSocket.shutdownOutput();
                 fileSocket.close();
                      SocketOperator.this.sockets.remove(clientSocket.getInetAddress());
                 SocketOperator.this.sockets.remove(fileSocket.getInetAddress());

                 Log.i("SocketOP", "CLOSING CONNECTION");
             }                       
    }       

    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("ReceiveConnection.run: when receiving connection ","");
}           
}   
}

public SocketOperator(IAppManager appManager) {
this.appManager = appManager;   
}


public String sendHttpRequest(String params)
{       
URL url;
String result = new String();
try 
{
    url = new URL(AUTHENTICATION_SERVER_ADDRESS);
    HttpURLConnection connection;
    connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    connection.setDoOutput(true);

    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(connection.getOutputStream());

    out.println(params);
    out.close();

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(
                    connection.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine;

    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        result = result.concat(inputLine);              
    }
    in.close();         
} 
catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} 
catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}           

if (result.length() == 0) {
    result = HTTP_REQUEST_FAILED;
}

return result;


}


public boolean sendMessage(String message, String ip, int port) 
{
try {


    String[] str = ip.split("\\.");

    byte[] IP = new byte[str.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {

        IP[i] = (byte) Integer.parseInt(str[i]);                
    }
    Socket socket = getSocket(InetAddress.getByAddress(IP), port);
    if (socket == null) {
        return false;
    }

    PrintWriter out = null;
    out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
    //OutputStreamWriter outputStream = new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
    //outputStream.write("Text");
   // outputStream.flush();
    String flag = "Text";
    message = message+flag;
    out.println(message);
} catch (UnknownHostException e) {          
    return false;
    //e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    return false;           
    //e.printStackTrace();
}

return true;        
}




public int startListening(int portNo) 
{
listening = true;

try {
    serverSocket = new ServerSocket(portNo);
    this.listeningPort = portNo;
} catch (IOException e) {           

    //e.printStackTrace();
    this.listeningPort = 0;
    return 0;
}

while (listening) {
    try {
        new ReceiveConnection(serverSocket.accept()).start();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        //e.printStackTrace();              
        return 2;
    }
}

try {
    serverSocket.close();
} catch (IOException e) {           
    Log.e("Exception server socket", "Exception when closing server socket");
    return 3;
}


return 1;
}


public void stopListening() 
{
this.listening = false;
}

private Socket getSocket(InetAddress addr, int portNo) 
{
Socket socket = null;
if (sockets.containsKey(addr) == true) 
{
    socket = sockets.get(addr);
    // check the status of the socket
    if  ( socket.isConnected() == false ||
          socket.isInputShutdown() == true ||
          socket.isOutputShutdown() == true ||
          socket.getPort() != portNo 
         )  
    {           
        // if socket is not suitable,  then create a new socket
        sockets.remove(addr);               
        try {
            socket.shutdownInput();
            socket.shutdownOutput();
            socket.close();
            socket = new Socket(addr, portNo);
            sockets.put(addr, socket);
        } 
        catch (IOException e) {                 
            Log.e("getSocket: when closing and removing", "");
        }               
    }
}
else  
{
    try {
        socket = new Socket(addr, portNo);
        sockets.put(addr, socket);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("getSocket: when creating", "");              
    }                   
}
return socket;      
}


public void exit() 
{           
for (Iterator<Socket> iterator = sockets.values().iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) 
{
    Socket socket = (Socket) iterator.next();
    try {
        socket.shutdownInput();
        socket.shutdownOutput();
        socket.close();
    } catch (IOException e) 
    {               
    }       
}

sockets.clear();
this.stopListening();
appManager = null;
//      timer.cancel();     
}


public int getListeningPort() {

return this.listeningPort;
}


@Override
public boolean sendFile(String ip, int port) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub


try {


    String[] str = ip.split("\\.");

    byte[] IP = new byte[str.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {

        IP[i] = (byte) Integer.parseInt(str[i]);


    }
    Socket socket = getSocket(InetAddress.getByAddress(IP), port);
    if (socket == null) {
        return false;
    }
    Log.i("SocketOP", "sendFILE-1");
   File  f = new File("/sdcard/chats/gas.jpg/");



   BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(f));
int readData;
   byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];   
   bis.read(buffer, 0,buffer.length);
  OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();

  while((readData=bis.read(buffer))!=-1){
      os.write(buffer,0,readData);


   Log.i("SocketOP", "sendFILE-3");
   }









} catch (IOException e) {
    return false;           
    //e.printStackTrace();
}
//  Toast.makeText(this, "Lvbvhhging...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

return true;        
}
}
```

This is my IMService service that runs and calls startlistening. i am totally cluless. its giving me an error as suspected. how do i go about resolving this now..
IMService code block :

```
public void onCreate() 
{       
     mNM = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    // Display a notification about us starting.  We put an icon in the status bar.
 //   showNotification();
    conManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);


    // Timer is used to take the friendList info every UPDATE_TIME_PERIOD;
    timer = new Timer();   

    Thread thread = new Thread()
    {
        @Override
        public void run() {         

            //socketOperator.startListening(LISTENING_PORT_NO);
            Random random = new Random();
            int tryCount = 0;
            while (socketOperator.startListening(10000 +     random.nextInt(20000))      == 0 )
            {       
                tryCount++; 
                if (tryCount > 10)
                {
                    // if it can't listen a port after trying 10 times,    give up...
                    break;
                }

            }
        }
    };      
    thread.start();

}
```

Comment: Does it work if you don't check for "Text" in ReceiveConnection? If you don't use BufferedReader and suppose that you can receive only files, not messages.

Comment: i tried it, commented out the condition now only sending the inputstream is to the method receive file and its receiving 0 bytes now...

Comment: i still used the buffered reader though..would not using it help?

Comment: Yes. Try to get rid of BufferedReader and see how it works.

Comment: i got rid of it. its pretty much receiving the file now but there is still data loss and i cant open the file cuz its incomplete. what do i do? and lets say if this is the way to go then how do i condition it for receiving text since i am not using the bufferedReader now?

Comment: 1. I don't think there is easy way to handle 2 kind of data in single socket. It will be much easier to have 2 separate sockets - one for messages and one for files.

2. About data loss. When you read file from system and write it to socket you use `(bytesRead = fileIn.read(buffer)) > 0`, but it should be `!= -1`. I'm not sure it will help, but may be.

3. Why do you use `ByteArrayOutputStream` in `fileReceived`? You can write directlry to `BufferedOutputStream`.

Comment: if its appropriate,can you maybe,kindly show me how to do that in the context of what i am trying to accomplish. it has frustrated me.

Comment: if you could put it as a solution? i shall be extremely thankful. also the 2 sockets thing..if you could please.

Comment: and also there is an issue now.in my IMService im having an error. no clue what to do :S

Answer (score 1):

Try this for fileReceived

```
public void fileReceived(InputStream is)
    throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    Log.i("IMSERVICE", "FILERECCC-1");


    if (is!= null) {
        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        BufferedOutputStream bos = null;
        try {
            fos = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/chats/gas1.jpg/");
            bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
            byte[] aByte = new byte[1024];
            int bytesRead;

            while ((bytesRead = is.read(aByte)) != -1) {
                bos.write(aByte, 0, bytesRead);
            }
            bos.flush();
            bos.close();
            Log.i("IMSERVICE", "FILERECCC-2");

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            // Do exception handling
        }
    }
}}
```

**EDIT**

You can use 2 sockets, listening on different ports. E.g.

```
MESSAGE_PORT = 20000
FILE_PORT = 20001
```

And you run 2 `ReceiveConnection`s, e.g. `ReceiveFileConnection` and `ReceiveMessageConnection`. I don't know where do you start port listening, it's not in your code above.

In client you'll also need to split sending to 2 part, message sender sends to MESSAGE_PORT and file sends files to FILE_PORT.

**EDIT2**

http://pastebin.com/MfMuSF2Q

- I split `ReceiveConnection` into 2 classes `ReceiveMessageConnection` and `ReceiveFileConnection`.
- I modified method `startListening`, so it takes parameter which listener we want to start message or file. So you need to call it twice like

  startListening(MESSAGE_PORT, true);

  startListening(FILE_PORT, false);

But call them in different threads.

To send message you call `sendMessage("Message", ip, MESSAGE_PORT)` and for files `sendFile(ip, FILE_PORT)`.

Hope this will help.

Comment: but how do i put the condition now? this would only work if i have no condition for text and file. u mentioned using 2 different sockets right. if you could explain it a bit further.

Comment: i have added the complete socketoperator file now..please have a look.

Comment: @hardy.exe I cannot see your file. What have you added?

Comment: i put it under your last comment. kindly check again if u cant view it then ill put it again.

Comment: kindly check now. i have edited it. right under my original code.

Comment: @hardy.exe yes. Check my changes.

Comment: thank you so much im just about to test it. i just want to know do i need to make anymore changes anywhere or do i just try this one? the explanation u presented above is a little confusing, where u say call it twice and call them  in different threads. i did not really get that. are u telling me to do it or have u done it. if u could elaborate just a little.

Comment: You used only 1 ReceiveConnection to listen for both messages and files. Now you have 2 connections - one listen for messages and another for files. So instead of calling startListening once, you have to call it twice to start both of them. Also `startListening` method blocks current thread until we stopped listen. So you need 2 threads: one for listening messages and one for listening files.

Comment: i just pasted the code block from my IMService service at the end the original code. its giving me an error as suspected. if you could have a look at it. thank u so much youve been a life saver..

Comment: its erroneous at :public  ReceiveConnection(Socket socket) it says change it to constructor or change method type to void.at both the places. "new ReceiveMessageConnection(serverSocket.accept()).start();" this is also generating error at both places both for message and for file. it askes to change the arguments or create a constructor for these. help.HELP!

Comment: I CHANGED class name so constructor also should be CHANGED, change `ReceiveConnection` to `ReceiveMessageConnection`.

Comment: *face palms himself* okay and what about the bit in the imservice. what do i do there? while (socketOperator.startListening(10000 +     random.nextInt(20000))      == 0 )
            this part.

Comment: Why do start listening random ports? You can choose 2 and listen them.

Comment: startListening(MESSAGE_PORT, true); startListening(FILE_PORT, false); // how do i do this one? u said i would have to call these twice but in different threads :S and also in my socketop code can u tell me how do i listen to these 2 ports and how do i know which one is for the client and which one is for the server.

Comment: Nikita can i mail you or something..my whole project is screwed for some reason thats probably because i have interfaces that u dont know about, i have a mysql database also. i go to the localhost and check for the port and then forward it to communicate between emulators. nothing is working now nothing! it doesnt oprn any port, it uses the same ip for all the emulators :'( can i mail u my project. please. help me m doomed..

Comment: Send here nikelandjelo@gmail.com

Comment: @hardy + Nikelandjelo ..... Can you please send me this code ..... I need it.... Thanks in advance  email at : i070470@nu.edu.pk

Comment: @Nikita Beloglazov please see this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9700066/how-to-send-data-form-socket-to-serversocket-in-android  and help, waiting for some positive response